# How does a operating system pick up data from different file systems

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems

I'm trying to understand this.

Let's say Windows for example. It uses `NTFS`. If one attached a USB stick to their computer, this file system would most likely be `FAT32`. Or if we were connected to a remote server using `ZFS` for example it can still pick up data such as files from different file systems.

How would a operating system understand a different file system to the one it is primarily using is connected, and be able to pick up the data that it wants, as if it was all the same file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in one question. The first - the identification of the file system, which depends on the type of GPT partition tables, or MBR. MBR for all sufficiently uniquely determined partition IDs. For GPT - GUIDs for different partition types. Respectively - with the help of GUID and ID set the file system type. Moment number two of this problem - access to the file system - driver FS.

The second problem - access to the file system through services on the network. Then the question is, do you have a a client service and whether there is connectivity to the server that is running the service. FS driver is not needed on the client machine, access to the file system occurs at servere.Servis remote access to the file system creates a virtual representation of your file tree to which it provides access and communication with these files from your side come through the client part.